# Is it ideal to use a .MDB file type over .ACCDB file type?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am running several macros that perform read and write commands to MS Access using `DAO` in Excel. My current file type is `.MDB` I encountered database corruption after 2 weeks of running back and forth read and writes to MS Access. I was previously referencing `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library` but switched over to `Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library`. Could my database corruption be due to file type and connection type, or just referencing the wrong library? I am providing the code is use to upload and retrieve data from MS Access.

**Load Table from MS Access to Excel**

```vb
Sub loadData()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = OpenDatabase("Z:\UBPB CRM Project\pbsbackup.mdb")
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("pbsload")
qdf!pbsbranch = initialLogin.ComboBox1

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

If rst.EOF Then
    rst.Close

End If

    Do

Sheet3.Range("A8").CopyFromRecordset rst
    Loop Until rst.EOF

rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Add record from Excel userform to MS Access**

```vb
Sub AddnewRecord()

Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to PBS Database......"
Set db = OpenDatabase("Z:\UBPB CRM Project\pbsbackup.mdb")
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("addclient")


Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Client Data to PBS server...."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

    qdf!pbsbranch = Sheet4.Range("A2")
    qdf!pbsclient = addnewClient.client
    qdf!pbspriority = addnewClient.priority_
    qdf!pbscontact = addnewClient.contact
    qdf!pbsresult = addnewClient.result
    qdf!pbsnextsteps = addnewClient.segmentType
    qdf!pbsattempts = addnewClient.Label11
    qdf!pbsnotes = addnewClient.notes


qdf.Execute dbFailOnError


qdf.Close

Application.StatusBar = "Upload Successful!"

Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Update record from Excel userform to MS Access**

```vb
Sub pbsupdate()
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to PBS Database......"
Set db = OpenDatabase("Z:\UBPB CRM Project\pbsbackup.mdb")
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("pbsupdate")

Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Client Data to PBS server...."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

    qdf!pbskey = dialer.key
    qdf!pbsclient = dialer.client
    qdf!pbspriority = dialer.priority_
    qdf!pbssource = dialer.priority
    qdf!pbslastcontact = dialer.contact
    qdf!pbsresult = dialer.result
    qdf!pbsnextsteps = dialer.segmentType
    qdf!pbsattempts = dialer.Label11 + dialer.Label11 + 1
    qdf!pbsnotes = dialer.notes


Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

qdf.Close
db.Close
Application.StatusBar = "Upload Successful!"

Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Simultaneous writing by 32bit and 64bit versions of any library will corrupt the database. But usually `compact and repair` menu fixes it.

Comment: @4dmonster unfortunately `compact and repair` could not save and restore my database. Kept getting `Run-time error 3343 Unrecognized Database Format` error

Comment: try `JetComp` utility from Microsoft, or try to `Compat and repair` by different versions of Access. And may be source of corruption is network failure (as I understand `Z:` is mapped network share)